# How to fetch $POST data and put in database

Tags: php, joomla

Hi i have a simple form that uploads files and i want to get the id value using $POST and put in the database but my code is incorrect. Here is my code. I just want to ask if im doing the passing and fetching of $POST correctly? thanks

```html
echo "<form action='process.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='uploadfile'>";
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='100000' />";
 echo "<select name='selectedValue'>";
 echo '<option selected="selected">' .'Choose a User'. '</option>';
  foreach ($registeredUsers as $key => $value) {
   $registered = JFactory::getUser($value);
  echo '<option name="id" value="'.$registered->id.'">'.$registered->name.'</option>';

  }
  echo "</select>";
  echo "Choose a file to Upload:";
  echo "<input name='uploadedfile' type='file' /> <br/>";
  echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">';
  echo "</form>";
```

Here is the process.php file.

```html
if(isset($_POST['selectedValue']))
        {
            $selectedValue = $_POST['id'];

            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);

            $query = "INSERT INTO sample_table ('user_id') VALUES ('$_POST[id]')"

            $db->setQuery($query);
            $result = $db->execute();
        }
```

Comment: replace this if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { ...  }

Comment: & files should be in $_FILES array

Comment: `$query = "INSERT INTO sample_table ('user_id') VALUES ('$_POST[id]')"` means your ID is a char. Is it ?

 `$query = "INSERT INTO sample_table ('user_id') VALUES ('".$_POST[id]."')" // for a char`
OR

 `$query = "INSERT INTO sample_table ('user_id') VALUES (".$_POST[id].')" // for a int`

Comment: Why don't you just add some "echo"'s somewhere to check where your error is... ? ^^

Comment: What happen if you do `echo $_POST['id'];` in your `if` to see what's the problem. If it says nothing, use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`. Does it change anything ?

Comment: I would suggest using the JForm API that is part of Joomla and then it will handle filtering as well. JFormFieldMedia handles file uploads, you can always extend it if you need something slightly different.  Also JFormFieldUser will deal with the user field.  Just make an xml string to represent the fields you need.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "<form action='process.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='uploadfile'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='100000' />";
echo "<select name='id'>";
echo '<option selected="selected">' .'Choose a User'. '</option>';
foreach ($registeredUsers as $key => $value) {
    $registered = JFactory::getUser($value);
    echo '<option value="'.$registered->id.'">'.$registered->name.'</option>';

}
echo "</select>";
echo "Choose a file to Upload:";
echo "<input name='uploadedfile' type='file' /> <br/>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">';
echo "</form>";
```

process.php

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $selectedValue = $_POST['id'];

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query = "INSERT INTO sample_table ('user_id') VALUES ('$selectedValue')";

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->execute();
}
```

Okay. So you had some problems, you've set the "name" on the options, which is wrong, you have to set that on the .
Second, you missed a semicolon at the end on $query.
And last, i've chaged to check if the a value has been chosed from the dropdown and to set selectedValue to that, and use that in the query.

Comment: It'd be nice to add some SQL injection protection.

Comment: True, but that wasn't what he were saking for :) And maybe this is some internal things that he only will have access to, then it doesn't really matter :)

Comment: not my downvote, but you probably got it because of this `('user_id')` that is a column and not a value. It requires no quotes, or use ticks `\``. Going over OP's many questions where I submitted one too; seems OP probably doesn't know how Stack rolls here ;-) and hasn't accepted any solutions given.